# Zoom in and out a ViewBox with mouse scroll and use mouse pointer location as zoom origin

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, mousewheel, viewbox

The title is pretty much self-explaining, but to add to the facts, I'm using a large `Canvas` inside my `ViewBox` and my `ViewBox` is placed inside a `ScrollViewer`. I've set the event handlers for the `MouseMove` and `MouseWheel`, and I'm using `myViewbox.Width` and `myViewbox.Height` to change the zoom level (which I'm not sure is the proper way). Now I'm stuck on how to set the zoom origin to my mouse pointer location.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372560/zooming-to-mouse-point-with-scrollview-and-viewbox-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better way is to use the RenderTransform property (particularly ScaleTransform in your case). Have a read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx)

this could be useful: [Pan & Zoom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/wpf-pan-zoom-image)

Comment: how is it done with a scrollview, a viewbox and a canvas nested in each other? which one must have its `RenderTransform` property set?