# Move (zoom and pan) around a large Canvas

Tags: wpf, animation, canvas, zooming, pan

I have a lot of images placed on a canvas (~150 pages converted PDF). 
I would like to be able to move around from one region to another of this canvas by animating the movement (zoom and pan).

My animation keys are in a listbox. I have a "play" button to play all. 
When I click an animation key, my "camera" automatically moves to the defined location.

It's a kind of "Prezi wall".

Answer (score 0):

This is only half or three quarters of an answer really, but hopefully you can fill in the gaps. You could try using the [`VisualBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). First you set up the visual that the `VisualBrush` will paint using your full `Canvas`:

```
VisualBrush visualBrush = new VisualBrush();
visualBrush.Visual = yourCanvasElement;
```

You then paint with the `Brush` onto, let's say, a `Rectangle` element:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
...
rectangle.Fill = visualBrush;
```

You can then use the `VisualBrush.Viewbox` property to move the content about. Now I *think* that there is some way of zooming in and out, but I can't remember at the moment.

Alternatively, you could use the [`ViewBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can get your zooming effect by changing the size of the content and the `ViewBox` and get your panning effect by using a `ScrollViewer`. There's a post on StackOverflow that demonstrates this, so please take a look at the [Zooming To Mouse Point With ScrollView and ViewBox in Wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372560/zooming-to-mouse-point-with-scrollview-and-viewbox-in-wpf) post for more help with this method.