# How to maintain the panning state after zoom-in, pan and again zoom the image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, zooming

My requirement is, want to zoom and pan the image programmatically.

1. Zoom-in and zoom-out programmatically using button click
2. Panning the image using touch interaction.

For the above requirement, I am facing the issue on maintaining panning state.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Zoom the image using button click.
2. Pan the image using touch move.
3. Now zoom-in or zoom-out using button click

**Issue:** Panning state is not maintained and image is zoomed from the over all center position of image.

**Expected behavior:** Image should be zoomed from center of the visual bounds area and panning state should be maintained.

I have attached my demo sample [here](https://github.com/Eswaran17392/OnlineSample)

Here is my code [C#]:

```
MatrixTransform ZoomMatrixTransform;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid.DataContext = this;
    updateZoom = true;
}

bool updateZoom;
    
public int ZoomFactor
{
    get => (int)GetValue(ZoomFactorProperty); 
    set => SetValue(ZoomFactorProperty, value);
}
    
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ZoomFactor. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ZoomFactorProperty = 
 DependencyProperty.Register("ZoomFactor", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(100, OnZoomFactorChanged));
    
private static void OnZoomFactorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = d as MainWindow;
    int factor = (int)e.NewValue;
    if (factor >= 50 && factor <= 400 && window.updateZoom)
    {
        window.PerformZoom(e.NewValue);
    }
}

private void PerformZoom(object newValue)
{          
    float zoomValue = Convert.ToInt32(newValue) / 100f;
    Matrix matrix = Matrix.Identity;
    var scaleX = zoomValue;
    var scaleY = zoomValue;
    matrix.Scale(scaleX, scaleY);
    
    ZoomMatrixTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
    
    foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children)
    {
        child.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        child.RenderTransform = ZoomMatrixTransform;
    }
}
    
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ZoomFactor += 10;
        
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => ZoomFactor -= 10;
        
private void Panel_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var element = sender as UIElement;
    var position = e.GetPosition(panel.Children[0]);
    
    var matrix = ZoomMatrixTransform == null 
                 ? Matrix.Identity 
                 : ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix;
    
    var scale = e.Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1);
    
    matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
    var factor = (int)(matrix.M11 * 100);
    updateZoom = false;
    ZoomFactor = factor <= 50 ? 50 : factor >= 400 ? 400 : factor;
    updateZoom = true;
    
    if (factor >= 50 && factor <= 400)
    {
        ZoomMatrixTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
        foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children)
        {
            child.RenderTransform = ZoomMatrixTransform;
        }
    }
}

Point start;
Point origin;

private void Panel_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{           
    if (ZoomMatrixTransform != null && ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix != Matrix.Identity)
    {
        start = e.GetPosition(panel);
        origin = new Point(ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix.OffsetX, 
        ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix.OffsetY);
        editorImage.CaptureMouse();
    }
    
    Point position;

    if (this.editorImage != null)
    {
        position = e.GetPosition(this.editorImage);
    }
    else
    { 
        position = e.GetPosition(panel);
    }
}
    
private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{           
    Point position;
    if (this.editorImage != null)
    {
        position = e.GetPosition(this.editorImage);
    }
    else
    { 
        position = e.GetPosition(this.panel);
    }
    //CheckValueIsInRange(position);
    
    if (editorImage.IsMouseCaptured && ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix != Matrix.Identity)
    {
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement;
        if (editorImage != null)
        {
            frameworkElement = editorImage;
        }
        else
        {
            frameworkElement = panel;
        }
    
        var elementBounds = new Rect(frameworkElement.RenderSize);
        var transformedBounds = editorImage.TransformToAncestor(panel).TransformBounds(elementBounds);
    
        var matrix = ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix;
        Vector vector = start - e.GetPosition(panel);
    
        if (transformedBounds.Left < 0 && vector.X <= 0)
        {
            matrix.OffsetX = origin.X - vector.X;
        }
        else if (vector.X >= 0 && transformedBounds.Right >= panel.ActualWidth)
        {
            matrix.OffsetX = origin.X - vector.X;
        }

        if (transformedBounds.Top < 0 && vector.Y <= 0)
        {
            matrix.OffsetY = origin.Y - vector.Y;
        }
        else if (vector.Y >= 0 && transformedBounds.Bottom >= panel.ActualHeight)
        {
            matrix.OffsetY = origin.Y - vector.Y;
        }
    
        ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix = matrix;
        foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children)
        {
            child.RenderTransform = ZoomMatrixTransform;
        }
    }
}
    
private void Panel_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    => editorImage.ReleaseMouseCapture();
       
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix = Matrix.Identity;
    foreach (UIElement child in panel.Children)
    {
        child.RenderTransform = ZoomMatrixTransform;
    }
}
```

I have tried different approach to maintain the panning state, but it is not working. Please share your idea on this.

Comment: You should always keep the existng `ZoomMatrixTransform.Matrix`, e.g. as in Panel_MouseWheel. Do not reset it it PerformZoom.

Comment: Also note that it is redundant to set the RenderTransform property each time you update the Matrix. Assign a MatrixTransform once, and later only update the Matrix property of the existing MatrixTransform.

Comment: Zoom at a given position e.g. like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353109/1136211

Comment: I have tried with not resetting the matrix in PerformZoom method. But with render transform origin as (0.5, 0.5) it takes the original image center, not the center of the view port. How can I get the center of the panned image.