# Changed MatrixTransform result control out of bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, transform

I'm writing an image control with zoom, and wrap into a usercontrol.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp20.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp20"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="Green">
        <Grid x:Name="gridMain" MouseWheel="gridMain_MouseWheel">
            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                <Grid x:Name="SIGrid">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform >
                        <TransformGroup >
                            <MatrixTransform x:Name="MatrixTransform" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>

                    <Image x:Name="PART_MainImage" Source="/Grid.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Uniform"  StretchDirection="Both" Visibility="Visible">
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


private void gridMain_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MatrixTransform == null)
                    return;

                var pos = e.GetPosition(PART_MainImage);
                var scale = e.Delta > 0 ? 1.1 : 1 / 1.1;
                var matrix = MatrixTransform.Matrix;
                if (matrix.M11 <= 0.1 && e.Delta < 0)
                    return;
                MatrixTransform.Matrix = new Matrix(scale, 0, 0, scale, pos.X - (scale * pos.X), pos.Y - (scale * pos.Y)) * matrix;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Then in MainWindow, I just put it into a grid.

```
<Grid Background="Red"/>

<Grid  Grid.Row="1">
    <local:UserControl1/>
</Grid>
```

So when I zoom in, the image goes out of the usercontrol bounds, it should always in the green area.

[image]

How to fix?

I made a sample [here](https://github.com/hupo376787/WPFZoomOutOfBounds).

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353109/1136211

Comment: Yes, but it still zoom out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Finally, `ClipToBounds` saved me.

```
<Grid Background="Green" ClipToBounds="True">
```