# How can I move a Picture with just "drag" the picture?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

So I want to make a funtunality like in Windows when you display a Picture that when you zoom in you can just move the Picture with the mouse. I already got the zoom part in my project:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scroll" Margin="40"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Canvas
                MouseWheel="Container_MouseWheel" x:Name="canvas">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Image x:Name="img"  Source="{Binding imageSource}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                    </Viewbox>
                </Canvas>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

and the Code in the MouseWheel Event:

```
  var element = sender as UIElement;
        var position = e.GetPosition(element);
        var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        var scale = e.Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1); // choose appropriate scaling factor

        matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
        element.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
```

but now Ive got the Problem that when I zoom I cant just click and hold the Image with the mouse and move to an another part of the picture, if you dont really know what I mean just open an Image on windows zoom in and then hold the mouse and move in the picture.

What I have tried was to add these 3 Events to my Canvas and this is the code behind for the 3 Events:

```
  private Image draggedImage;
    private Point mousePosition;
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = e.Source as Image;

        if (image != null && canvas.CaptureMouse())
        {
            mousePosition = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            draggedImage = image;
            Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 1); // in case of multiple images
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedImage != null)
        {
            canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            Panel.SetZIndex(draggedImage, 0);
            draggedImage = null;
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedImage != null)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition(canvas);
            var offset = position - mousePosition;
            mousePosition = position;
            Canvas.SetLeft(draggedImage, Canvas.GetLeft(draggedImage) + offset.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(draggedImage, Canvas.GetTop(draggedImage) + offset.Y);
        }
    }
```

but this didnt work saddly, does anyone has an Idea on how to make it work?

Comment: As a note, it makes no sense to put an Image in a Viewbox in a Canvas. The Viewbox has no effect, bcause a Canvas never applies any sizing on its child elements. Also setting Grid.ColumnSpan on the Image is totally pointless.

Comment: Drop the ScrollViewer and the Viewbox and apply a translation to the Matrix.

Comment: Also `element.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);` is not necessary. In the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353109/1136211) there is `transform.Matrix = matrix;`

Comment: I removed the scrollViewer and Viewbox but what you mean by "Translation to the Matrix"? Because from now its not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mix layout (i.e. set Canvas.Left/Top) and render transformations. If you zoom by means of a RenderTransform, you should also pan by the same RenderTransform.

Here is a simple example where the MouseMove handler also manipulates the RenderTransform of the Image element.

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas"
        Background="Transparent"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasMouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="CanvasMouseMove"
        MouseWheel="CanvasMouseWheel">
    <Image x:Name="image" Source=...>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Note that mouse positions are determined differently for pan and zoom, in order to get an "unscaled" offset for panning, but an origin point relative to the Image for zooming.

```
private Point? mousePosition;

private void CanvasMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (canvas.CaptureMouse())
    {
        mousePosition = e.GetPosition(canvas); // position in Canvas
    }
}

private void CanvasMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    mousePosition = null;
}

private void CanvasMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mousePosition.HasValue)
    {
        var position = e.GetPosition(canvas); // position in Canvas
        var translation = position - mousePosition.Value;
        mousePosition = position;

        var transform = (MatrixTransform)image.RenderTransform;
        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        matrix.Translate(translation.X, translation.Y);
        transform.Matrix = matrix;
    }
}

private void CanvasMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition(image); // position in Image
    var scale = e.Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1);

    var transform = (MatrixTransform)image.RenderTransform;
    var matrix = transform.Matrix;
    matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
    transform.Matrix = matrix;
}
```