# WPF - creating (image) wall or prezi effect?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I want to develop Windows WPF application using Kinect with great GUI/NUI. I've found really nice examples of user interfaces that could be even more admirable using Kinect device. For example: prezi effects - http://prezi.com/jipjiqvj6dsc/about-perspective/ one big wall and really nice zooming / moving. I was thinking about something similar for Metro UI too.

Do you know how to create those nice gui elements in the WPF? Or maybe you heard about good resources about this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found really nice project which includes solution for my problem: http://jarloo.com/code/projects/jot/

Nice discussion on stackoverflow: [Pan & Zoom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/wpf-pan-zoom-image)

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is Josh Blake's upcomming book (you can get the MEAP preview now) and the "NaturalShow" sample app it includes.  You can get that code at http://blakenui.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, NaturalShow looks really nice but unfortunately there is now usable sources for it :(. But this information really helped me.