# Pan with animation ,WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want create a nice effect with a Pan in Wpf and when i release the mouse there is an animation ,do you have some advice to share about this feature?

EDIT 
I want drag a Grid in a canvas and when i release the mouse on the Grid i want create an effect of transition.
Hope it is clear.
Thanks so much for your attention.

Cheers

Comment: Please provide more informaton about what do you want

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/wpf-pan-zoom-image

Comment: start by reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx