# Extra lines appear when EdgeMode.Aliased option is used in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have encountered a very odd problem today using WPF. Here is the code I have used to draw 10000 `LineGeometry` objects.

```
// Draw 10000 lines
var g = new GeometryGroup();
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var n = 1;
while (n < 10000)
{
    x = x + 20;
    if (x > 600)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = y + 20;
    }
    var l = new LineGeometry
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(x, y),
        EndPoint = new Point(x, y + 15)
    };
    g.Children.Add(l);
    n++;
}

var drawing = new GeometryDrawing {Geometry = g};
var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
drawingGroup.Children.Add(drawing);
var myPen = new Pen {Thickness = 1, Brush = Brushes.Yellow};
drawing.Pen = myPen;

var myImage = new Image {Stretch = Stretch.None, Margin = new Thickness(10)};
var myDrawingImage = new DrawingImage {Drawing = drawingGroup};

myImage.Source = myDrawingImage;
canvas.Children.Add(myImage);
```

[image: Before EdgeMode.Aliased]

Now as you can see the result is not crisp and I used the code below to achieve better results.

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(myImage, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

The image gets crisp but has another side effects as you can see in the image below.

1. Some lines are now shown.
2. Some extra odd lines are shown.

[image: After EdgeMode.Aliased]

I have included the full code so you can experiment this for yourself.

**Note:**
I'm using ZoomBorder class around the Canvas canvas.
[Pan & Zoom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/pan-zoom-image)

Comment: If you let the loop run to 30000 lines the diagonal lines disappear :)

Comment: Have you tried using           RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(myImage, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality); instead?

Comment: I can only confirm that running it without RenderingOptions produces a crisp output. Running it with RenderingOptions produces diagonal lines but still lines are all there for me. Feels like a bug in WPF aliasing to me.

Comment: @BlueM Actually it seems that a Zoom class that I have is somehow messing with the image. I removed the class and everything seems ok! It is odd that this Zoom class doesn't interfere when I draw the `Line` objects as `Shape` but when I use `LineGeometry` the image gets messed up.

Comment: @d.moncada I tested this and it totally solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use the zoom class and I get REALLY odd behavior. I will post it as answer.

Comment: @BlueM Thanks. I would like to know the reason this happens.

Comment: @Vahid sweet. Glad I could help, I added it as an answer so that is' more visible if anyone else comes across the same / similar need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using

`RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(myImage, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);`

instead?

You can also set it on your Canvas control as well..

```
<Canvas RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"> ...
```

Comment: He said he solved it already but the question remains why `EdgeMode.Antialiased` shows that strange behavior. Also his first example without RenderingOptions shows clear crisp lines for me, obviously his Zoom class made problems.

Comment: So we better don't mess with RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode :-)

Comment: Yeah, usually in WPF, whenever I want to fix scaling / quality issues when it comes to Images, I use BitmapScalingMode and it seems to always solve the problem

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. But the problem remains when the above  code is not used.

Comment: Seems he encountered a real bug in WPF, as this problem starts as soon as more than 8192 objects are added into the GeometryGroup.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a real answer but I want add something to that odd behavior of WPF in hope somebody can come up with a real explanation.

I added a single line from (0,0)-(20000,20000). Creating 8000 line objects (n < 8000) produces the expected result like this:

[image]

Now, creating 9000 line objects will totally mess it up, but see for yourself:
[image]

Without setting `EdgeMode.Aliased` it looks fine, even with high counts of objects.

Comment: I tried this and it gives me the correct results without ZoomBorder class. Are you sure that this gives you the above image? Maybe a variable is changed somewhere. I updated the question.

Comment: Add this outside the loop: `g.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 0), new Point(20000, 20000)));` and `RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(myImage, EdgeMode.Aliased);`

Comment: Wow, this must be a real bug with internal flags. It comes down as soon as we have 8193 objects added, it starts to get out of control. So there seems to be a limit of 8192 objects for it to be properly working.

Comment: You are right! It does mess up the image, this is very odd actually.

Comment: This is very alarming. I want to use WPF for a CAD program I'm developing and it even doesn't get such simple things right.