# Blurry LineGeometry in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the code below to draw `LineGeometry` objects. But somehow I'm getting blurry lines. Any idea why this is happening?

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var n = 0;

    while (n<1000)
    {
        x = x + 20;
        if (x > 1200)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = y + 20;
        }

        var l = new LineGeometry
        {
            StartPoint = new Point(x, y),
            EndPoint = new Point(x, y + 15)
        };
        MyGroup.Children.Add(l);

        n++;
    }

}


<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Width="1200" Height="700">
        <Path x:Name="MyPath" Stroke="Wheat" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup x:Name="MyGroup" >

                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>

        </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Here is the result I get:
[image]

Comment: @HenkHolterman I updated the question. The lines on the left are blurry.

Comment: Try setting `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on your Window.

Comment: @DanBryant Didn't help. It made all of the lines blurry.

Comment: Wasn't this resolved in your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539408/extra-lines-appear-when-edgemode-aliased-option-is-used-in-wpf

Comment: @d.moncada They look similar but here I'm adding the LineGeomtries to Path. You can test the code above.

Comment: WPF was designed with the assumption that this would *not* be a problem today.  Pretty sad that this didn't happen, seems that only programmers that like to visit their local Apple Store spend the money on the hardware they need.  WPF will forever be labeled as "cheap".  Because that's the way it looks and nobody sees the real problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Luckily I solved this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for this:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="LearnDrawing.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="700" Width="1200" Background="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Width="1200" Height="700">
            <Path x:Name="MyPath">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup x:Name="MyGroup">
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var n = 0;
while (n < 1000)
{
    x = x + 20;
    if (x > 600)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = y + 20;
    }
    var myLineGeometry = new LineGeometry
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(x, y),
        EndPoint = new Point(x, y + 15)
    };

    MyGroup.Children.Add(myLineGeometry);
    n++;
}

MyPath.Stroke = Brushes.White;
MyPath.SetValue(RenderOptions.EdgeModeProperty, EdgeMode.Aliased);
MyPath.Data = MyGroup;
```

**Result**

[image]