# Preventing a scaled image from overwriting other elements in the window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am displaying a scaled image in an Image element with other elements in a window. The image starts out displayed as I would expect, with other elements visible, but the moment the window is resized the image overwrites the other elements.

It happens with non zero values for CentreX and CentreY

How can I limit the scaled image to its own element?

```
<Grid>
    <Label>Testing</Label>
    <Image Name="TheImage">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"
                        CenterX="10" CenterY="10" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Grid>


    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
        bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"Image.jpg");
        bi.EndInit();

        TheImage.Source = bi;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried putting the image and the other controls in a `<StackPanel>`?

Comment: I would have sworn I had, but clearly I hadn't. That resolves the problem in my test app, It also changes things for the actual app this is for, if not quite fixes it, so that gives me hope. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. No need for an answer then :-)

Comment: @XAMlMAX Actually it only works when the Centre values are 0, any positive values and the bitmap overwrites the label again.

Comment: Should you have a look at this [MSDN-WPF-transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.centerx(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @XAMlMAX That's what I think I am doing, setting CentreX/Y to the centre of the image, but the image displays over everything else in the window

Comment: This might be a little weird but could you put the image in a StackPanel and the rest of controls outside of it i.e. `<StackPanel><TextBlock/><StackPanel><Image/></StackPanel></StackPanel>` but this is a pure guess.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I have found an answer, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanel (or DockPanel) is required, but the key is to ["place the image within a Border with it's ClipToBounds property set to True."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772360/259)

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Testing</Label>
    <Border ClipToBounds="True">
        <Image Name="TheImage">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"
                    CenterX="10" CenterY="10" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```