# Canvas and Image Share Zoom and Offset for Grid Overlay

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

This is in reference to the following answer: [c# pan and zoom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/pan-zoom-image#)

I want to add a grid that scales along with the image.  I've tried adding a canvas with `IsHitTestVisible = "False"` and use `border.RenderTransforms.Value.OffsetX` which gives a value, but doesn't update.  I also tried `((TransformGroup)border.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is ScaleTransform))` but it provides a MatrixTransform instead of a Scale.

Basically, I'm looking to share the `ScaleTransform` and `TranslateTransform` values from the ZoomBorder class object and place them into a canvas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some trials, I found that a simple `canvas.RenderTransform = image.RenderTransform` works well.