# How to enable Panning on left mouse button in PanAndZoom WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, zooming, pan

I am using WPF.PanAndZoom library for pan and zooming but by default it has panning enabled on right mouse button click but i need it on left mouse button click but found no documentation for this. Anyone can help please?

If you have suggestion for any other similar library, that will also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version on Github has this implemented due to this issue:

https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/PanAndZoom/issues/14

In fact this issue appears to have been opened by you! Within the XAML you can use the PanButton="Left" property to set this.

The NuGET packaged version 0.5.1 does not appear to have this code implemented yet.

Comment: https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/PanAndZoom/issues/16 - the developer has explained an alternative to using the standard NuGet source.

Comment: Yes i have already fixed that issue by combining the old code of this library available at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6782715/6482266 having left button panning option, with the nuget library code.