# WPF Scrollviewer not adjusting to content

Tags: .net, wpf, image, user-interface, zooming

I need to show an image in my WPF application, overlay it with transparent canvas and allow user to draw on it. User must be able to zoom image (in and out) and "navigate" in image while zoomed in using some kind of scrollbars docked to bottom and right of the window. To enable image zoom, I used [ZoomBorder control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/pan-zoom-image), described in second answer. So this is my XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imageScroll" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
  <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="backgroundZoomBorder" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Width="{Binding CurrentImageWidth}" Height="{Binding CurrentImageHeight}"  >
     <Grid x:Name="gridDrawing" MouseLeftButtonDown="background_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="background_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="background_MouseLeftButtonUp">                           
       <Image  x:Name="mainImage"  Source="{Binding Path=WriteableBmp}" />
       <Canvas x:Name="canvasDrawing"  Background="Transparent" />
     </Grid>
  </local:ZoomBorder>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works, however, the scollviewer is not adjusting to content's size, it's still the same, if the image is zoomed in to maximum, or is zoomed out to minimum. It should disappear if the image is smaller than window area, or have bigger range when image is zoomed. Can I anyhow bind ScrollViever to Image's transformed size or something? Or is there any better control for this instead of ScrollViewer?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ScrollViewer` will never work with the `ZoomBorder` control because it is using a `RenderTransform`. A `RenderTransform` manipulates what you see **after** it has gone through the layout system. Because of this, its size never changes and thus the `ScrollViewer` will never activate.

By modifying the `ZoomBorder` to use `LayoutTransform`, you can get the zooming (scroll wheel) functionality to work and the `ScrollViewer` will activate. However, getting panning to work with the mouse will take more significant modifications.

Here is some example code that works:

ZoomBorder using LayoutTransform

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SO
{
    public class ZoomBorder : Border
    {
        private FrameworkElement child;

        private ScaleTransform GetScaleTransform(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            return (ScaleTransform)((TransformGroup)element.LayoutTransform)
              .Children.First(tr => tr is ScaleTransform);
        }

        public override UIElement Child
        {
            get => base.Child;
            set
            {
                if (value != null && value != Child)
                    Initialize(value);
                base.Child = value;
            }
        }

        public void Initialize(UIElement element)
        {
            child = (FrameworkElement)element;

            if (child == null) return;

            var group = new TransformGroup();
            var st = new ScaleTransform();

            @group.Children.Add(st);

            child.LayoutTransform = @group;
            child.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);

            MouseWheel += child_MouseWheel;
            PreviewMouseRightButtonDown += child_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            if (child == null) return;

            // reset zoom
            var st = GetScaleTransform(child);
            st.ScaleX = 1.0;
            st.ScaleY = 1.0;
        }

        #region Child Events
        private void child_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (child != null)
            {
                var st = GetScaleTransform(child);

                var zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;

                if (!(e.Delta > 0) && (st.ScaleX < .4 || st.ScaleY < .4)) return;

                st.ScaleX += zoom;
                st.ScaleY += zoom;
            }
        }

        void child_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Reset();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

ScrollViewerPanBehavior
A behavior that handles panning by dragging with the mouse.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace SO
{
    public class ScrollViewerPanBehavior : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
    {
        private UIElement content;
        private Point scrollMousePoint;
        private double scrollHorizontalOffset;
        private double scrollVerticalOffset;

        public ScrollViewerPanBehavior()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            content = (UIElement)AssociatedObject.Content;
            content.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnMouseLeftButtonDown;
            content.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
            content.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            content.CaptureMouse();
            AssociatedObject.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            scrollMousePoint = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
            scrollHorizontalOffset = AssociatedObject.HorizontalOffset;
            scrollVerticalOffset = AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset;
        }

        private void OnMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (content.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                var newVerticalOffset = scrollVerticalOffset + (scrollMousePoint.Y - e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject).Y);
                var newHorizontalOffset = scrollHorizontalOffset + (scrollMousePoint.X - e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject).X);

                AssociatedObject.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newVerticalOffset);
                AssociatedObject.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(newHorizontalOffset);
            }
        }

        private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            content.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            AssociatedObject.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<ScrollViewer
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ScrollViewerPanBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:ZoomBorder
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="ThumbsUp.png" />
        </Grid>
    </local:ZoomBorder>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This was fun to work on!

Comment: alright, I will give it a try with LayoutTransform, thank you very much

Comment: Thank you again, really good job with that code. However it's not working for me. Image is not zooming, and scroll viewer is still not adjusting. the only thing that seems to do zooming is Canvas placed in <Grid> after Image tag. I can;t understand why is this happening, I will let you know if I find out.

Comment: Allright, problem was in my XAML, silly mistake, I was binding images' width and height to ZoomBorder size, now I moved it to Grid tag, and it's working perfectly. You saved me, I can't thank you enough, God bless you.