# How to enable zooming in Component One C1Chart

Tags: c#, componentone

I am using c1 chart (Component One) to plot and I want to enable zooming feature. I think that I need mouse wheel event but I am not very advanced with that topic. The plot is inside to scroll viewer so I have to be becareful.

Comment: Don't think there is any in-built functionality for this and you will most likely have to apply your own scaletransform this should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741956/pan-zoom-image

Comment: @RandRandom There use image to render. Dont serve me, but thx for reply!

Comment: Doesn't matter if image or C1Chart every WPF control can be scaled/transformed. Zooming into an image is just the more common usecase.

Comment: chart.RenderTransform is not ScaleTransform in C1Chart and doesnt has an AxisX or AxisY attribute.

chart would be x:name in xaml for C1Chart

Comment: I have used the "ZoomBorder" (second answer from the question) and seems to work just fine -   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDzA7.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfss8.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbvOf.png

Comment: The error you are getting is probably that the first answer needs you to define a ScaleTransform in XAML eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t29UV.png

Comment: The ZoomBorder does it itself in the method `Initialize`

Comment: When Define 
<c1:C1Chart.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform/>
</c1:C1Chart.RenderTransform>

The compiler throw an error like: Nested types are not supported. I will test with ZoomBorder.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already done adding this to xaml.

```
    <c1:C1Chart.Actions>
        <c1:TranslateAction Modifiers="Shift" />
        <c1:ScaleAction Modifiers="Control" />
    </c1:C1Chart.Actions>
```

In xaml.cs:

```
chart.ActionEnter += new EventHandler(Actions_Enter);
chart.ActionLeave += new EventHandler(Actions_Leave);

        private void Actions_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void Actions_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ScaleAction)
            chart.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
        else if (sender is TranslateAction)
            chart.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        else
            chart.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
```